# Javascript String Company Issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

i return from php page an echo for test:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {

          e.preventDefault();

          $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'https://capelladb.000webhostapp.com/textExample.php',
            data: $('#form').serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                  var compare = data.localeCompare('testest');
                  console.log(data);
                  console.log(compare);
                  }
          });

        });
    });
```

Just for test, the data returns in the success method is typeof "string" with "testest", but when im comapre to 'testest', is return -1 into "compare" variable. why it happen ?

Console.log photo: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VSTUj.jpg

the PHP:

```
<?php
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");

    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "id1635462_capellam";
    $password = "capella2017";
    $dbname = "id1635462_capella";

    $userInput = $_POST['username'];
    $passwordInput = $_POST['password'];

    echo $userInput . $passwordInput;
?>
```

Comment: What's inside `data`? Just a string 'testest'? Are you sure it's identical?

Comment: what's the result of `console.log(data)`

Comment: From [mdn](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare): String.prototype.localeCompare() Return value: "A negative number if the reference string occurs before the compare string; positive if the reference string occurs after the compare string; 0 if they are equivalent."
Edit: Can you console log the value of data?

Comment: yes just "testest", console.log(data)="testest"

Comment: It should be 0 if you compare the same strings. For sure it's not the same string. Can you please share your echo in PHP too?

Comment: http://imgur.com/a/h7wWh
console.log(data);
console.log(compare);

Comment: <?php
 header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
 
 $servername = "localhost";
 $username = "id1635462_capellam";
 $password = "capella2017";
 $dbname = "id1635462_capella";

 $userInput = $_POST['username'];
 $passwordInput = $_POST['password'];
 
 echo $userInput . $passwordInput;
?>

Comment: and where do you see inside this code `echo "testest"`?

Comment: Don't post code in comments, add it to the question so you can format it.

Comment: What does `console.log(data.length)` say?

Comment: Omg, data.length return 9, and "testest" is 7, why that?

Comment: Try trimming the `data` string. `.trim()`

Comment: It probably has spaces or some other non printable characters at the end.

Comment: ok now it good length, but also dont return me 0

Comment: Still returning -1?

Comment: no sry, my fault, now ok, the problem was trim() needed, the string come dirty from the form :) thx all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` has empty spaces within.

You need to trim it, using `.trim()`.

See the code below:

```
$('#form').on('submit', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://capelladb.000webhostapp.com/textExample.php',
        data: $('#form').serialize(),
        success: function (data) {
            var compare = data.trim().localeCompare('testest');
            console.log(data);
            console.log(compare);
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Working example:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var data = 'testest      ';
  var test = data.localeCompare('testest');
  console.log('Not trimmed: ' + test);
  var test = data.trim().localeCompare('testest');
  console.log('Trimmed: ' + test);
};
```